# How to remove top and bottom default padding of Expansion tile for leading widget flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-widget

[image]

1. need to  remove padding to the list item of expansion tile widget
   please find the image for actual result . Expected result should remove the top bottom space

here is the code can anyone help me:

```
Theme(
      data: theme,
      child: ListTileTheme(
        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
        dense: true,
        child: ExpansionTile(
          title: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              GFCheckbox(
                inactiveBgColor: kColorPrimaryDark,
                inactiveBorderColor: Colors.white,
                customBgColor: kColorPrimaryDark,
                size: 15,
                activeIcon: const Icon(
                  Icons.check,
                  size: 15,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                activeBgColor: kColorPrimaryDark,
                onChanged: (value) {
                  setState(() {
                    isChecked = value;
                  });
                },
                value: isChecked,
                inactiveIcon: null,
              ),
              SizedBox(
                width: 5,
              ),
              textWidget(color: Colors.white, size: 12, text: root.title),
            ],
          ),
          key: PageStorageKey<DataList>(root),
          children: root.children.map(_buildTiles).toList(),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 2):

To remove top and bottom padding for expanded tile use property expandedHeaderPadding of ExpansionPanelList.

```
ExpansionPanelList(
    expandedHeaderPadding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 0),
    ...
)
```

Comment: How? This question is about ExpansionTile and not ExpansionPanelList ExpansionTile not has this property..

Answer (score 1):

Try below code add `childrenPadding` and `tilePadding`

```
  ExpansionTile(
      childrenPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
      tilePadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
   ),
```

Try to use [**`MediaQuery.removePadding`**](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/MediaQuery/MediaQuery.removePadding.html)

```
MediaQuery.removePadding(
      removeTop: true,
      removeBottom: true,
      // removeLeft: true,
      // removeRight: true,
      context: context,
      child: ExpansionTile(
        childrenPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
        tilePadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
      ),
    ),
```

Comment: it is removing only left and right not able to remove top and bottom padding

Comment: @gopinath check my updated answer

Comment: not working do i have any alternative plugin to use this

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
ListTileTheme(
   contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
   dense: true,
   horizontalTitleGap: 0.0,
   minLeadingWidth: 0,
   child: ExpansionTile(...)
)
```

Comment: no such arugments are showing in below null safety versions

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick if you wrap the `ExpensionTile` widgets with the `ExpansionPanelList` widget.

To remove the top padding you can use the `expandedHeaderPadding` property and for the bottom padding you can use the `materialGapSize` property like so:

```dart
ExpansionPanelList(
  materialGapSize: 0,
  expandedHeaderPadding: EdgeInsets.zero,
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your ExpansionTile with `ListTileTheme(minVerticalPadding: 0.0)`

i.e.

```
ListTileTheme(
            contentPadding: EdgeInsets.zero // this also removes horizontal padding
            minVerticalPadding: 0.0,
            child: ExpansionTile(
              dense: true,
              title: YourCardTileTitle(),
              // ...
            ),
          ),
```